# When using CSS transformation, how to avoid an element to overflow its parent?

Tags: css

I'm using CSS transformation to rotate some elements. However, rotated elements may render partially outside its parent.

Is it possible to avoid this behavior?

To illustrate my thoughts, [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5TZ3/4) that highlight this.

There is two divs :

```
<div id="g">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

and few css rules:

```
#g {
    background:silver;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin:100px 100px 100px 100px;
    border:solid 6px green
}
#inner {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;

}
```

In fact, the blue rectangle should not render outside the gray rectangle.

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

The main idea behind this question, is to add some kind of viewport with interactivity, but never outside the viewport.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#g`. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5TZ3/5/.

It should look like this:

```
#g {
    background:silver;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin:100px 100px 100px 100px;
    border:solid 6px green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;

}
```

That'll give you:

[image]

Comment: you even wrote `overflow` in your title :]